# Inputting csv to train with them

Tags: tensorflow

I have a CNN model that I previously tested before. However, I am new to importing my own data, and I keep getting errors. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, and what could be the proper way to import the data so the model can run? Are there any resources I could use, such as books or guides online?

Here is my current code;

```
code

https://pastebin.com/wKtidYGL
```

The test csv is (624,12000)
The train csv is (624,362)
The test and train labels are also (11999,1) and (361,1)

Comment: Please post the errors and the relevant code where the errors occur.

Comment: The error is after the input layer, where it says that it it is expecting ndimm 3, but got 2.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow developers have made a bunch of useful  CSV processing functions in order to make them easily feedable to your training model.

I would recommend reading the CSV section of this official [documentation page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/datasets_quickstart).

```
import iris_data
train_path, test_path = iris_data.maybe_download()

ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset(train_path).skip(1)

# Metadata describing the text columns
COLUMNS = ['SepalLength', 'SepalWidth',
       'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth',
       'label']
FIELD_DEFAULTS = [[0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0], [0]]

def _parse_line(line):
   # Decode the line into its fields
   fields = tf.decode_csv(line, FIELD_DEFAULTS)

   # Pack the result into a dictionary
   features = dict(zip(COLUMNS,fields))

   # Separate the label from the features
   label = features.pop('label')

   return features, label

   ds = ds.map(_parse_line)
   print(ds)
```

Comment: How should my csv be set up so it can work that way? I also am confused by how to feed in my labels. Should they be in the same csv?